# Crawling links with no-follow tag and dynamically generated URLs - using urllib3

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, urllib3

Experts,

I am trying to crawl and download files, if they're present, from a web-site using **urllib3** and **BeautifulSoup**. I am able to crawl the domain upto the page where the link for downloading the file exists. However, after that when I try to request the URL using urllib3, as follows, to download the linked file

```
http = urllib3.PoolManager();
page = http.request('GET', URL);
```

I end up getting only the URL string being downloaded and not the linked file. Upon inspecting the page, the URL has been marked 
`<a rel="no-follow" href="URL">.` And when I download the file linked with the URL, I end up downloading forbidden 403 response as follows,

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>403 Forbidden</TITLE>
<BASE href="/error_docs/"><!--[if lte IE 6]></BASE><![endif]-->
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<H1>Forbidden</H1>
You do not have permission to access this document.
<P>
<HR>
<ADDRESS>
Web Server at kkssraiadmk.com
</ADDRESS>
</BODY>
</HTML>

<!--
- Unfortunately, Microsoft has added a clever new
- "feature" to Internet Explorer. If the text of
- an error's message is "too small", specifically
- less than 512 bytes, Internet Explorer returns
- its own error message. You can turn that off,
- but it's pretty tricky to find switch called
- "smart error messages". That means, of course,
- that short error messages are censored by default.
- IIS always returns error messages that are long
- enough to make Internet Explorer happy. The
- workaround is pretty simple: pad the error
- message with a big comment like this to push it
- over the five hundred and twelve bytes minimum.
- Of course, that's exactly what you're reading
- right now.
-->
```

However, when I click the corresponding link from inspector console, I am able to view the file in the web browser.

Another thing is that, URL string is different for each refresh, as observed through "inspect element". As far my understanding goes the URL is being generated dynamically on every request.

My questions are as follows:

**Q.1:** Is it possible to follow the URL which has been marked "no-follow" using **urllib3** and parse the contents or download the file? If so, how can that be done? I've tried supplying user-agent, as follows,

```
user_agent = {"user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0"}
```

but that doesn't solve the problem, I think due to the dynamically generated URL strings

**Q.2** Even, if I can follow the "no-follow" link, how to fetch the file linked with the URL string,

```
/39f6f7c6abfdf34203421d37729bd20409508bd087bcdf96fa3cb7f6/doeE7UiXssBTML8DSEzmtU8MiFGpNRqg1F/1840
```

Any insight and help on, how to go about downloading the files would be of much help and appreciated?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is using urllib3 a requirement? You could just use the requests lib.
`import requests`
requests.get(url).text

Comment: Thanks @ElvirMuslic. Though it is not a requirement, "requests" library is built on top of "urllib3" and I am curious, would "requests.get(url).text deals with dynamically generated URL strings?

Comment: Didn't know, that however in most kind of situations it worked for me.(for user-agent and such issues). However, As for dynamically generated content, no such library can help you. Unless there's some kind of API or some other way to request specifically that content I haven't found a way to do this. 
I use Selenium for anything dynamic (javascript or other) generated. It's pretty easy to use, very slow but does the job (would recommend only if software, not time demanding) There are other but I found this method most competent and constantly developing.

Comment: Mm. I get that. Let me give selenium a try. As for thy dynamic stuff, only the URL string is dynamically generated, not all the page content, and it is different every time for the same linked file.

Comment: Oh only the URL, well if it's really just the URL address then you should have no issues with `requests` unless to get to that URL you need javascript and it is not visible/rendering by other means (only browser) and you can use BeautifulSoup for parsing the data.

Comment: Thanks @ElvirMuslic. Would requests crawl through AJAX call links?

Comment: You'd have to try @RussellB Sorry for the late answer.